# Security Role to Allow a View Customization ONLY and NOT Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

Is there a way to create a Security Role so users assigned to it would be able to customize a System View ONLY and NOT the Entity that the view is created on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, when a user has the rights to customize, he can customize all the options available with CRM UI.

Comment: Do you  know of any good documentation particularly about the Customization tab in the security roles configuration?

Comment: normally I check this MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547441.aspx